# llamar funcion bd sin "insert"

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Es sobre una base de datos, para llamar unas funciones en unas ventanas en java
O como quien dice, en lugar de que en programa tengas que escribir un comando, un “insert” por ejemplo, lo hagamos un botón que ya tenga esa función

Comment: Bueno y que has intentado?, que error te da .. debes subir un [example]

Answer (score 0):

Pues no entendí al 100% lo que quieres hacer, pero te dejo esto
Si quieres llamar al insert desde un botón pues nada más agregas al evento del botón la llamada al método que usas para hacer el insert, sólo le tienes que mandar los parámetros (los values) a guardar, ya sea por joption o textfields

Espero que te ayude

Comment: Es esta sección sólo se escribe las respuestas, si no es claro la pregunta usa los comentarios para pedir mayor detalles.

Comment: No tenía aún la reputación para comentar, sé que esto es un foro controlado y eso es bueno, pero a veces se pasan de querer estar controlando todo, como no podía comentar sólo quería tratar de ayudar, eso es todo, además de que sí le di una opción que puede usar para solucionar su problema